# Python select from SQL getting error

Tags: python, sql

I am writing the following query:

```
x1 = 5
y1 = 6
z1 = 0
SQL = ("SELECT Z FROM Points WHERE X =x1 AND Y = y1")
    for row in cursor.execute(SQL):
        z1 = row.Zcor
```

I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "../ppp.py", line 38, in 
>           for row in cursor.execute(SQLp1z):
>       pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][\xc4\xf0\xe0\xe9\xe2\xe5\xf0 ODBC Microsoft Access] \xcd\xe5\xee\xef\xf0\xe5\xe4\xe5\xeb\xe5\xed\xed\xe0\xff \xf4\xf3\xed\xea\xf6\xe8\xff 'convert' \xe2 \xe2\xfb\xf0\xe0\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe8. (-3102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

What's the error in my code and what do I need to do in order to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: is your spacing off for the for loop or is that just how you copied it here?

Comment: take a look at this, it looks like you're not including variables in your query string properly.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not including variables in your string correctly. Use string formatting:

```
SQL = ("SELECT Z FROM Points WHERE X ={x1} AND Y ={y1}".format(x1=x1, y1=y1)
```

Or in python 3.6:

```
SQL = (f"SELECT Z FROM Points WHERE X ={x1} AND Y ={y1}")
```